# Native-Base - CheckBox inside List not getting checked

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I have imported CheckBox from NativeBase. On clicking the Checkbox, it calls the toggleCheckBox function  to either add or remove the item.ids from the array and also set the flag to true or false based on the contents of the array.

I can see that the toggleCheckBox function works properly and it sets the array with item ids properly and the flag is also fine on click of the CheckBox. But, the checkbox inside the ListItem is not checked when the checkbox is clicked though the toggle function is called properly.

I also noticed that the log "MS CB2: " right above the List is printed after clicking the CheckBox but the log inside the List 'MS insideList :' is not printed. I am assuming that List is not rendered after the toggleCheckBox function is called.
Here is the code:

```
class MSScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        //this.toggleCheckbox = this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          checkboxes : [],
          plans: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("MS inside componentDidMount");

        fetch('http://hostname:port/getData')
            .then((response) => {console.log('response'); return response.json();})
            .then((responseJson) => {console.log('responseData: '+responseJson); this.setState({isLoading : false, plans : responseJson}); return;})
            .catch((err) => {console.log(err)});  
    }

    toggleCheckbox(id) {
        let checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;

        if(checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(id)){
          const index = checkboxes.indexOf(id);
          checkboxes.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          checkboxes = checkboxes.concat(id);
        }

        this.setState({checkboxes});
        console.log("MS check a4: "+checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(id))
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
        }

        const plans = this.state.plans;
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        const checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;
        console.log("MS CB1: "+checkboxes)

        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <View>
                        {console.log("MS CB2: "+checkboxes)}
                        <List
                            dataArray={plans.data}
                            renderRow={(item, i) => {
                                console.log('MS insideList : '+checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(item.id))
                                return(
                                <ListItem 
                                    key={item.id}
                                    >
                                    <Left>
                                        <CheckBox
                                            onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(item.id)}
                                            checked={checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(item.id)}                                            
                                            />
                                    </Left>
                                    <Text>
                                        {item.name}
                                    </Text>
                                </ListItem>)}}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

How do I get the CheckBox to get checked inside the List?

For the benefit of the other users, here is the code fix based on the suggestion from Supriya in the comments below:

**SOLUTION**

```
<FlatList
    extraData={this.state}
    data={plans.data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        const itemName = item.name;     
        return(
        <ListItem>
                <CheckBox
                    onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(item.id)}
                    checked={checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(item.id)}                                            
                    />
            <Body>
                <Text style={styles.planText}>
                    {item.name}
                </Text>
            </Body>
        </ListItem>)}}
/>
```

**Version:**

native-base@2.3.5

react-native@0.50.4

Device: Android

CRNA app with Expo

Comment: Did you check this with NativeBase KitchenSink?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand your question Supriya. I have referred Nativebase KitchenSink code. However, my problem is if i copy-paste the Checkbox code outside the List with hard-coded values, the checkbox gets checked properly. But, if I place the Checkbox inside the List, on clicking it though the toggle function works properly, the checkbox doesn't get checked. Please note that when the toggle function is called inside the List, the console.log statements inside the List never gets printed only the ones outside the List gets printed

Comment: There is a similar issue on github, https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/989

Comment: Many thanks Supriya. I followed the FlatList example in the link that you provided and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar issue on github, https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/989 with solution

Answer (score 1):

It works with straightforward code without listItem.
The following example handles the checkboxes as radio buttons, but the onPress functions can be changed easily to allow multiple selection.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class SignupScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <CheckBox checked={this.state.one}
            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            onPress={this.onePressed.bind(this)}/>
          <Text>One</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <CheckBox checked={this.state.two}
            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            onPress={this.twoPressed.bind(this)}/>
          <Text>Two</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <CheckBox checked={this.state.three}
            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            onPress={this.threePressed.bind(this)}/>
          <Text>Three</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  // checkbox functions
  // if clicked button was set, only clear it
  // otherwise, set it and clear the others
  onePressed() {
    if (this.state.one)
      this.setState({ one: false });
    else
      this.setState({ one: true, two: false, three: false });
  }

  twoPressed() {
    if (this.state.two)
      this.setState({ two: false });
    else
      this.setState({ one: false, two: true, three: false });
  }

  threePressed() {
    if (this.state.three)
      this.setState({ three: false });
    else
      this.setState({ one: false, two: false, three: true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Native base for web and was stuck on the same issue. The resolution I came with was to wrap the element inside a Pressable and then disable the default event using stopPropagation event.

here's the link to the snack for this - https://snack.expo.dev/B472JfR6C